AWS SAM esbuild fails when importing values from internal dependency with npm workspaces
I have a monorepo with npm workspaces, which contains a shared-types workspace that exposes type definitions and a few values to a backend workspace (AWS SAM + Typescript) and a frontend workspace (Vite+React+Typescript).
Any values (variables and enums) defined in shared-types work fine in the frontend Vite project. However, the esbuild process triggered by sam build fails on any imported variable or enum from shared-types. (The type definitions in shared-types work fine in the AWS SAM project - but I guess that is because these are not runtime and discarded in the esbuild process). Of course I build the shared-types workspace before I run sam build.
The error:
Error: NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle - Esbuild Failed: ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "@myProject/shared-types"
I have been searching for a solution for several days without success. Can anyone see the problem?
Directory structure of workspaces:
.
└── packages
    ├── BACKEND
    ├── SHARED-TYPES
    └── FRONTEND

[root] package.json (excerpt)
{
  "name": "@myProject/fullstack-monorepo",
  "workspaces": [packages/*"],
  // ...
}

packages/SHARED-TYPES/package.json
{
    "name": "@myProject/shared-types",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc --build",
        "watch": "tsc --build --watch"
    },
    // ...
}


packages/SHARED-TYPES/tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2020",
        "module": "es2020",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "composite": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "emitDeclarationOnly": false,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "incremental": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"]
}

packages/BACKEND/package.json (excerpt)
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@myProject/shared-types": "file:../SHARED-TYPES",
  }
}

AWS SAM template.yaml excerpt:
GetMetadataAllSurveys:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            # ...
        Metadata:
            BuildMethod: esbuild
            BuildProperties:
                EntryPoints:
                    - src/handlers/myHandler.ts
                External: ["@aws-sdk/*"]

